# apply a function on only one value of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, key-value, pca

I have a dictionary which looks like this:

```
{'image': array([[[173, 179, 201],
        [173, 179, 201],
        [171, 179, 200],
        ...,
        [180, 191, 213],
        [179, 190, 212],
        [179, 190, 212]],
       ...,
        [255,   0, 254],
        [255,   0, 254],
        [255,   0, 254]]]), 'index': 504, 'filename': 'Q50499.jpg'}
```

I would like to apply the PCA function that I wrote only on the array of 'image' and leave 'index' and 'filename' unchanged.
So as a result I want another dictionary that looks just like this, but PCA has been implemented on the numpy arrey.
Do you know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the dictionary, then replace the `image` element with the result of the function.

```
new_d = d.copy()
new_d['image'] = pca(new_d['image'])
```